# PayPal Here Documentation

Tags: paypal

Does anyone know the location of any documentation relating to "PayPal Here" integration?

I've scoured the web including the PayPal website but haven't found anything helpful, and their "support forum" points back here so I thought I'd ask.  There seems to be lots of documentation for their API's but nothing for their "PayPal Here" integration.

Answer (score 4):

Here's our latest documentation:

https://github.com/paypal/here-sideloader-api-samples

Also please let me know what arguments you were looking for that were missing...

Comment: This documentation is now maintained here: https://github.com/paypal/here-sideloader-api-samples/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the actual Here API's are still in early beta stages and won't be publicly released until later this year.

Comment: We're using their current implementation and it works pretty well with our app, but we're not able to expand much on what we have.  I'm hoping some documentation on it will let us send/receive some additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for PayPal Here Sideloader API documentation Tim posted about it on the developer blog at https://www.paypal-labs.com/devblog/paypal-here-sideloader-api/.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  We're using source code similar to the samples shown, but I was hoping to find out if there are any additional parameters we can pass to/receive from PPH.  It's not anything that's a show stopper so I'll keep my eyes open for the documentation from PayPal.

Comment: I believe Tim documented all the parameters that are currently exposed in the API.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as you'll get: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/1#issuecomment-14680084 unless you do like I did and send them a lot of emails for the most up to date version, lol. One of those links has the soon to be released documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Here SDKs for iOS and Android are now published on developer.paypal.com:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/pph-sdk-overview/

There is also a version for Windows 8.1+ in Beta, available upon request.  You can email DL-PayPal-Here-SDK@ebay.com for help with any of these.